# What is the best approach to draw a 3D polygon with one or more holes in it?

Tags: wpf, 3d

[image: Drawing]

Like the title says what is the best approach to draw in c# the rectangle with holes like the image?
Can it be done in WPF 3D or do i need a library from a third party? 
Which 3d party can i use then?

Comment: You can try this 3D toolkit: https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit

Comment: You have to construct this shape using preliminary shapes (Usually Triangles or Quads) which the GPUs understand.

Comment: Do you know [Eyeshot](http://www.devdept.com) for WPF?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will definitely try the helix toolkit. The eyeshot library also looks very promising but its not open source. It depends how good the helix toolkit is.